# Stop Core Data objects from auto-arranging

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a NSTableView and I binded my Array Controller to it. The Array Controller is binded to my Managed Object Context. Everything in the NSTableView works but the objects in my TableView rearranges randomly when I start up my app. For example, the order of [1,2,3] will suddenly change to [3,1,2] and this happens occasionally. I want it so that things stay in the order they were put when making them. How do I stop the rearranging?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not very familiar with NSArrayController, but according to the documentation you can add a *sort descriptor* to it.

Comment: Is it possible to add a sort descriptor that just tells it to order it the way I put it (The order it is when I add more rows)?

Answer (score 0):

The rows in the CoreData data store are not sorted! If you want to view them by creation date you need to add your own timestamp to every object and pass a sort descriptor to the fetch request.

Edit: If you are using SQLite as your CoreData store I recommend to have a look at the SQLite file. This will give you an idea on how CoreData works and explain why certain things (like unordered rows) are the way they are.

P.S. I use [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/) to inspect SQLite databases. It's not cheap but quite nice.

Comment: Thanks but how do I add a timestamp? Do I add a "creationData" attribute of type "Date".  Or how do I organize it by my timestamp.

Comment: Yes, create a new attribute of type date and initialize it with `[[NSDate alloc] init]` to receive a date object with the current date and time.